# Disable exception handling while debugging c++ project using Google Test

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, exception, googletest

I have my (native C++) DLL project and a corresponding test EXE project based on Google Test. While debugging my DLL via this EXE I have exceptions automatically handled by Google Test. So if my DLL throws an unhandled exception during debug, I expect to see error message from Visual Studio with debug session paused after the code caused exception. Instead, I have breakpoint triggered in gtest.cc. And if I disable `--gtest_break_on_failure` flag I will receive no breaks at all.

I found no such option in Google Test documentation. Have I missed it? I don't want to check "break when thrown" flag for different exceptions in Debug settings, because I'm only interested in unhandled ones.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The answer is in the Advanced page section called "[Disabling Catching Test-Thrown Exceptions](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#disabling-catching-test-thrown-exceptions)". What you have to do is invoke your binary with `--gtest_catch_exceptions=0`.